# Installing Wordcloud Package using Conda on a M1 Mac

Tags: python, macos, word-cloud, apple-m1

I'm relatively new in coding and wanted to start sentiment analysis project. One of my goals is to create a word cloud and I tried to install the Wordcloud package on my M1 Mac via conda-forge. But it seems like the package is not available in any library. I'm getting the following error message, when I try to install it:

`PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- wordcloud

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/label/cf202003/osx-arm64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/label/cf202003/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
- [https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch`](https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch%60)

Do some of you know if there is any other way to install Wordcloud ? Or is there a channel I can take a look at?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

According to below, you can use
“Conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud”
Command.

https://programmerah.com/mac-m1-how-to-solve-import-wordcloud-error-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-wordcloud-39497/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).